# Nbr of threads started by JNI_CreateJavaVM()

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When I call JNI_CreateJavaVM() on a 24 cores machine with 32GB using Ubuntu 10.10 gcc, it starts 26 threads. It seems like an overkill. Where is the number of threads created can be set ? Thank you.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? The number seems entirely reasonable; you'd really want one thread per core in your threadpool. Add a main thread and one for the garbage collector, and you have the 26 threads you see.

Comment: my app is not multithread for now...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use all cores, you can explicitly set the thread affinity of your process via `sched_set_affinity()`. (Windows has a similar mechanism).

Comment: I would have thought of a JVM setting